# Sequelize migrations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize and would like to know if anyone knows if there is a way to avoid the code duplication in Sequelize when using the migration functionality?

What I mean is that in the migration you would have something like this:

```
//migration-xyz.js
module.exports = {
  up: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {

      migration.createTable('Users',
      {
         name: DataTypes.STRING,
         surname: DataTypes.STRING
      });

  },

  down: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    // logic for reverting the changes
  }
}
```

But then the model would look something like this:

```
//user.js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    surname: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  return User;
};
```

Is there a way to get rid of the code duplication?

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: They're doing quite different things. As you have more migrations it would be less obvious what the final `User` Model was intended to be. I'd rather there be one source of truth for the `User` class than look across many migrations to discover its properties.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I do agree there should be one source or truth. Yet a model file with a DB schema and many migrations also with DB schema changes does not make things more 'one source of truth', on the contrary it makes things even more messy. Thus my question, is there a way to remove the duplication?

Comment: What duplication? If you have 10 migration files that all modify the `user` table, what does the Schema look like that you use in your app code? Migrations don't even need to live in the same source repository and they don't execute unless you specifically execute them.

Comment: Same problem here, I want to use migrates to create tables and keep the change record.
Migrations should(better) be auto generate when model we define changes, like south(django).

Answer (score 1):

As @WiredPrairie referenced in his/her comment, migrations and the attributes on a model are distinct things. Often we will create a model that has certain attributes and the associated migration to create the corresponding table. Later on more attributes will be added to the model and we will need to create a migration that adds columns for just the new attributes.

A way to remove the duplication would be to use `sequelize.sync` which creates your database from the model files. This has downsides though and should not be used on complex applications that are being deployed in different environments.

Maybe in the future the sequelize-cli will have a `create:migration --model [modelfile]` option where it will create the table for the corresponding model. This would have the same "duplication" of code but would make things a little faster.

Answer (score -1):

When you initially ran the migrations via sequelize-cli

it set up the folder structure as:

```
-config
-config/config.json
-migrations
-models
-models/index.js
```

If you make sure your model file:

```
//user.js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    surname: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  return User;
};
```

is in the models directory, it will automatically be picked up when you
require('./models');

So, I've used the following code to import the new models for that revision of the migration:

```
//migrations-xyz.js
var Models = require('../models');

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    /*
      Add altering commands here.
      Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.

      Example:
      return queryInterface.createTable('users', { id: Sequelize.INTEGER});
    */

    var tables = _.map(Models.sequelize.models, function(def){
      var model = Models[def],
          options = model.options,
          tableName = model.tableName,
          attributes = model.tableAttributes;

      return queryInterface.createTable(tableName, attributes, options);
    });
    return Promise.all(tables);
  },

 down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
   /*
    Add reverting commands here.
    Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.

    Example:
    return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
   */
      return Models.sequelize.drop({logging: true});
  }
};
```

Comment: What is the purpose to dynamically adjust **initial** migration content to the **current** state of the model? This doesn't make any sense. The migration should be a static patch.